# Gson JsonSyntaxException error while parsing

Tags: android, gson, android-json

I know exactly what the problem is. My attempts to solve it have been futile.

Here's the problem in the json input:

[image: Json]

As you can see, the item **option_value** is sometimes an array and sometimes it's just a simple string. My parser however, treats it as an array because that's how I've defined it:

```
....
public class Options
    {
        String product_option_id;
        String option_id;
        String name;
        String type;
        String required;
        List<OptionValue> option_value;
....

....
public class OptionValue
        {
            String product_option_value_id;
            String option_value_id;
            String name;
            String image;
            String price;
            String price_prefix;
....
```

How do I modify my class so that it is able to check if **option_value** is an array or simply a string and is treated as such?

Comment: Might be changes requires into JSON data, add one parameter isOption into your json and set true if option_value is a JsonArray, else set isOption false for option_value is a empty string. Also made changes into your code according isOption value.

Comment: Making changes in the json is not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: one possible solution : instead of empty string the default value of option_value would be null & it would be useful to check wheater its Json Array or not.

Comment: quick fix: try to get array in try and if exception comes then get string in catch. you can also get string in finally. :)